# Apache config to point requests in all possible subdir to main dir

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I would like to point all requests for a certain directory and all its possible subdirs to one documentroot.

So, for example, I get a lot of requests on many different subdirs here:
**domain.com/directory/and_all_possible_subdirs**

Point to the index.php file that resides in **domain.com/directory/**

What to add in apache2.conf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use mod_rewrite for achieving your goal, that will be much easier.
see http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls/5 for an example.
You "misuse" the 404 condition that arises when entering a "wrong" URL an redirect the user to the wanted file/page.